# Laravel QueryBuilder - hook before a query is executed

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to alter queries before execution, like for example

```
Event::listen('which event?', function($query) {
    $query->where('foo', 'bar');
});
```

so that a `Example::where('name', 'baz')->get()` would produce this sql code:

`select * from example where name = 'baz' and foo = 'bar'`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally best handled with a [global scope](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#global-scopes) on your model.

> Sometimes you may wish to define a scope that applies to all queries performed on a model. In essence, this is how Eloquent's own "soft delete" feature works. Global scopes are defined using a combination of PHP traits and an implementation of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ScopeInterface.